# Looping Through Recordsets

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a problem that is driving me nuts.

I need to update a recordset within a recordset.

The SQL t get the records that need to be update is:  "SELECT * FROM tmpInvoiceIntegration WHERE DocumentType='Debit'".

This should pull me all of the items that need to be updated, based on the records haing DEBIT as a Document Type.

Now, I need to update all of the records that have the same Document Number.

This is what I have:

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rst2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL1 As String
Dim strSQL2 As String

strSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM tmpInvoiceIntegrationRM10101 WHERE DistributionDocumentType='Debit' ORDER BY DistributionDocumentNumber"
strSQL2 = "SELECT tmpInvoiceIntegrationRM10101.DistributionDocumentNumber FROM tmpInvoiceIntegrationRM10101 WHERE tmpInvoiceIntegrationRM10101.[DistributionDocumentType])='Credit'"

Set rst1 = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL1, dbOpenDynaset)
Set rst2 = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL2, dbOpenDynaset)

If rst1.RecordCount = 0 Then Exit Sub

rst1.MoveFirst
' loop through each record in the first recordset
Do Until rst1.EOF
' If matching record is found then update field in
    ' second recordset to value you determine
If rst2.RecordCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
    rst2.MoveFirst
    Interval = 16384
Do Until rst2.EOF
    If rst1![DistributionDocumentNumber] = rs2!DistributionDocumentNumber Then
        rst2.Edit
        rst2![DistributionSequenceNum] = Interval
        rst2.Update
    End If
    
    rst2.MoveNext
    Interval = Interval + 16384
    Loop
    rst1.MoveNext
Loop

rst1.Close
rst2.Close

Set rst1 = Nothing
Set rst2 = Nothing

Set db = Nothing
```

I need to have it update the field 'DistributionSequenceNum' to multiples of 16384 in each document number (i.e. DistrbutionDocumentNumber 33297 would have the DistibutionSequenceNum records that are Credits to multiples of 16384.

There could be one record, there could be two, etc.

On top of that, each 'DistributionSequenceNum' ahouls have a Debit record that should be updated to 16384.

Confused yet?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Jeff

I tried the above code and received the following VBA error:

Error 424 'Object Required' on the following line:

Set rst1 = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL1, opendynaset)

Comment: Start by putting [`Option Explicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) at the top of each module. 
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time. 
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor. 
This is really a must have for VBA development.

Comment: You have declared `dbs` but are using `db`.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the **db**:

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database

Set db = CurrentDb
```

Comment: First line is Dim dbs As DAO.Database

And before the strSQL1 is the Set dbs=CurrentDb is already there.

Comment: No it isn't. And `db`, as you use later, is not the same as `dbs`.